# jQuery list elements taking the whole height of the parent verticaly

Tags: jquery, list, element, percentage

i have four icons displayed verticaly in a ul with a 100% height and a fixed width.
i want the icons to fit according to the actual size of the ul.

```
<div>  
    <ul id="user-actions">
       <li><i class="icon1"></i></li>
       <li><i class="icon2"></i></li>
       <li><i class="icon3"></i></li>
       <li><i class="icon4"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

exemple [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KzUeD/)

so i've tried to add some margin-top in % for the li's, but if the div' size changes, the li's stay put..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style for li tags

```
li{
    height: 25% !important;
}
```

Can this help?

Comment: i guess it does ! i don't understand though why it works with height and not with margin ? (thank you anyways)